# Delete a particular line of a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, text

Suppose we have a system that can record the information and remove them by ID

Suppose that information is stored in a file txt are stored.  separated  each person from other With ====
Suppose we have an individual ID and want to remove it,  I wrote the following code but does not work:

```
class Register():
def __init__(self):
    self.DB = open('student.txt','a+')

def addstu(self,s):
    form = str(s.id) + "\n"
    form += s.name + "\n"
    form += s.family + "\n"
    form += str(s.term) + "\n"
    form += s.major + "\n"
    form +=s.avg+"\n"
    form += "=" * 5+"\n"
    self.DB.write(form)
    self.DB.close()


def delstu(self,id):
    d=[]
    y=0
    f=self.DB.readlines()
    for line in f :
        if id in line:
            break
        y +=1
    for i in range (y,y+6):
       d += self.DB.readline(i)
    self.DB.close()
    u=open('student.txt','w')
    for w in d:
          print u.write(w)

    u.close()
```

The variable y is the line that led to the finds and 6 lines must then be removed. The six lines in

d put it, then using the array d the lines of the original file is deleted

When the program runs all the data can not be deleted

Unfortunately, my native language is not English. I hope my writing is correct

Comment: Maybe it would be nice if you'd describe what is not working. You provide an input, your expected output and the real output.

This will also help you to understand you problem better.

Besides I would strongly suggest you to use more descriptive variable and method names.

Comment: You'd probably be better served using Sqlite, not a text file, if you're trying to update/remove elements

Comment: Anyways, you're not deleting a particular line, it seems. You're trying to delete a student, which covers many lines

Comment: Every time you open the file for write access (`u=open('student.txt','w')`) you *truncate* the file to zero bytes.  If you are not going to read the whole thing into memory first (could bust memory), then you should copy to a new file those records that you don't wish to delete.

Comment: The other problem I see is that ANY operation closes the file and no further operations could be done. If you want to work with text-based DB you should keep the file name and on any operation open file in appropriate mode, then do what you need, then close file.